# Hiding code from html validation wrecks formatting

Tags: html, css, validation, cdata

So I grabbed this twitter widget from the twitter site for my website. I have the twitter widget which is in the html code like so

```
<div id="twitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitternamehere" data-widget-id="331777195053809665"> Tweets by @twitternamehere</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" >!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    </div>
```

The validation for XHTML1.0 of course picks up the data widget id is not valid. I tired it in html 4 also. I decided to wrap my code inside a CDATA tag to hide it from the validation. Like so,

```
<![CDATA[
My twitter widget + div
]]>
```

This however messes up my formatting for the widget which is supposed to be

```
#twitter{ 
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute; top:96px; left:116px; 
}
```

The CDATA tag basically makes it move into my other div formatting which is in the centre of the screen. I tried wrapping just the twitter script inside CDATA and had no luck.

Is there anyway I can get around this formatting error, or is there anyway I can hide this code from the validation in any other way?

Comment if you need more details.

Thanks

Comment: Validation isn't *that* important. If your site works on all major browsers, you're fine.

Comment: Yeah i know, but its for an assignment so i was unsure if i will be marked down or not